# Android Studio String types not allowed (at 'inputType' with value 'textMobileNo')

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and have added 2 inputs in my code but am getting the error 
Error:(38, 32) String types not allowed (at 'inputType' with value 'textMobileNo').
Error:(51, 32) String types not allowed (at 'inputType' with value 'textType').

Help Please

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobileno"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
        android:hint="@string/hint_mobileno"
        android:inputType="textMobileNo"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/input_register"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
        android:hint="@string/hint_type"
        android:inputType="textType"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/input_register"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />
```

Comment: you can only use pre-defined list of input-types, and there is no textMobileNo or textType there

Comment: check code autocomplete (ctrl+space in Android Studio) for the list of available options

Comment: Thank you, can I know where do I have to setup the pre-defined list for the input-types.

Comment: Got it thanks a million

Comment: you don't have to set it up. Android has a pre-defined list of available input types. And you are trying to use one that is not in this list. Check the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values for `android:inputType` are a bit off:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mobileno"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
    android:hint="@string/hint_mobileno"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/input_register"
    android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/input_register_bg"
    android:hint="@string/hint_type"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/input_register"
    android:textColorHint="@color/input_register_hint" />
```

For a full list of values (and explanations!!) you can use, refer to the android documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType